# How to override proxy settings while installing npm and related plugins?

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend, npm-install, node-modules

I have tried to override the proxy settings in my machine since I am unable and not authorized to add or remove the proxy settings in my machine.

However I have installed node.js, is there any way to override proxy and https-proxy settings through code in order to install npm and related plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to update the proxy settings by using `proxy-agent` and `properties-reader` node packages. find below sample script this may help to get desire result.

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var proxy = require('proxy-agent');
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader(process.env.HOMEPATH + '\\.npmrc');
var strProxy = properties.get('proxy');

process.env['http_proxy'] = strProxy;

aws.config.update({
    httpOptions: {
        agent: proxy(strProxy)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am not trying to work with AWS, just I tried to install webpack in my machine. Do you think, it will work?